# Azure Mobile Services - Connect to Existing Database

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'd like to create a Azure Mobile Service (.NET) that reads / writes from an existing database that is being used by an MVC 5 app. I've been trying, without luck, for the better part of a day to make this happen through the few examples that exist on the internet.

I've just now come across this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962208/two-azure-mobile-services-net-backend-sharing-the-same-database)  where Carlos Figueira says that a mobile service creates a new schema with the same name as the service name and all access is done via that schema and the user that has permission to that schema. If this is the case, how will I be able to have my mobile service connect to an **existing** table, if it always creates new tables in the new schema?

Also, I'm getting the impression that mobile services using .NET is much happier if I don't attempt to connect to an existing DB. Is this the case?

Comment: This scenario should definitely work. See this tutorial for a walkthrough--http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/. You need to change the schema that you are connecting to (and the permissions), but this is easy to do with the .NET backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services will only work with tables in the new schema (with the service name).  In order to work with an existing database, you need to transfer the tables to this schema, and then you will need to rename all your PK columns to "id" (lowercase).  Once you have done that, the tables still don't show up in the Data tab in the management interface, but you can 'add' them and then it will connect and you can work with your existing data.

See this link for full walkthrough:  http://www.strathweb.com/2012/12/using-existing-database-with-azure-mobile-services/

Comment: thats pretty much old article. how do we do that on current azure portal? we must use Easy tables I guess. can we do that with C# backend as well?